# Redux: one form per record for potentially thousands of records

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, redux, redux-form

**Scenario:** I have a list of assets `<AssetList />`. As the user scrolls down to the bottom of the list my app will lazy load the rest of the assets. So depending on how far the user scrolls down, hundreds, if not thousands of assets could be loaded.

**The problem:** Clicking each asset `<Asset />` will expand it and allow the user to edit its fields (name, content, ..) The transition should be seamless. As I see it, each asset needs to be a form. My concerns are 1) **Approach** and 2) **Performance**.

**Approach:** The approach I am taking here is using one form per record using `redux-form`. Are there any alternatives to this that also enforce the flux architecture? Is this a common problem?

Another potential approach here is to modify the state tree as such and have one form per the entire asset list:

```
{
   assets: {..}, 
   assetForm: {..} 
}
```

And clicking an `<Asset />` will instead trigger the appropriate action which will cascade to a reducer which will update the `assetForm` state.

**Performance:** My biggest concern by far. I don't mind the large number of forms on the page but what concerns me is that each form is associated with a redux store reducer (or at least that's what I think utils such as redux-form do). So in other words, does potentially having thousands of reducers impact performance?

My apologies if my assumptions are incorrect. I am relatively new to react & redux.

Answer (score 5):

I think you raise valid concerns on a fairly common use case. To address some of your questions, I think your approach is valid except you may want to tweak it a little to avoid having so many forms created. I haven't personally used `redux-form` so I'll let those with more experience add more answers or comments, but from a more abstract point of view, you should only have a form when the user clicks in an `Asset`, therefore, I suggest only rendering the form when the `Asset` is clicked. This way you will only have as many forms as the user needs, dramatically less than one per `Asset`.

As for management of the store if you were to have to initialize a form per `Asset`, again without specific `redux-form` experience, couldn't you ensure you have a fairly simple state structure and only append to it when a form is initialized? That is, think of a state var called `assetForms` which is an object where each key is the unique id of the `Asset` and the value is another object with the form data. This way, again, you only keep as many state objects as there are `Assets`.

Hope that clears up some of the confusion but feel free to expand on your question if you need more specifics.

Comment: Thank you @ZekeDroid. I actually considered having one form per entire asset list initially. I just updated my question with more specifics. I think your approach is sound. As to your second part where you refer to ``assetForms`` - that is managed by redux-form. You supply it with a form key which could be your asset ID and it saves the form state on it, dictionary style.

Comment: Ah I see, and how complicated are your forms exactly? I would almost recommend managing the fields yourself as it would make it much simpler to work with. You can have each Asset initialized with an ID and a callback for `onChange` so that the parent can, on this callback, fire an action like `{ type: 'ASSET_CHANGED', assetID: 'some_id', fieldsChanged: { name: 'foo', description: 'bar' } }`. This way you have absolutely no extra information and, again, only as many state fields as the user attempts to change them.

Comment: Just so I follow. First off, you would recommend one form per the entire list of assets?

Comment: Er not sure. I think you're talking about backend form? As in one that has a way to post directly? I'm personally not fond of them and would recommend simple `input`s and http requests through your redux actions.

Comment: Ah no actually I use redux-form does a ``preventDefault`` on the form and handles them asynchronously by invoking either an onChange or onSubmit callback. When I said one form for the entire list I just meant that there will be a form (or just fields, the form part doesn't really matter) that will have that loaded in and out depending on which asset a user clicks on. Does that sound about right?

Comment: Gotcha. You meant the UI part, yeah so I would have one form per `Asset`, but only render it when a user clicks. You can do that with React by doing selective rendering, meaning that based on the current state (for example, `isEditing` which could be set to `true` on click) you render either your static `Asset` (a bunch of spans or whatever) OR if `isEditing`, render a form. Is that what you meant? And if you do it such that clicking outside of the `Asset` sets `isEditing` to false, you will only ever have one form on your page at any given time.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I meant. Thanks again!